# Printing out a specific line from a text file using python

Tags: python, file, loops, matrix, graph

This is for a school exercise, also I'm new to this so please do bear with me a bit. I have a graph 'fileName' and a program below which outputs an adjacency matrix. The matrix is placed in a list like so:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

With this adjacency matrix, it lists a theoretical sport match-up where teams who played against each other are listed '1' and those who have not are listed '0'. I have another file 'fileName2' which lists a bunch of team names where each line of the text file has a single team name. I'm aiming to print out the names of the teams who have not played a game between each other. My code so far can be found below (it has a lot of debugging artifacts, I know, it's messy):

```
vertices = int(input('How many vertices are there in the graph?'))
fileName = input("What's the name of the file of graph to read?")
fileName2 = input("What's the name of the file of team names to read?")

f1 = open(fileName, 'r')
f2 = open(fileName2, 'r')

# Create adjacency matrix skeleton for storing later

adjMatrix = [ [0] * vertices for i in range(vertices) ]
# adjMatrix = [[0] * vertices] * vertices

# Looping through the file to obtain the connecting vertices

for line in f1:
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    line = line.split(' ')
    i = 0
    for vert in line:
        line[i] = int(vert)
        i += 1

    j = line[0]
    k = line[1]

    adjMatrix[j][k] = 1
    adjMatrix[k][j] = 1

print(adjMatrix)

# Print out the teams who have yet to play against each other

for m in range(vertices):
    # print(adjMatrix[m])
    for n in range(vertices):
        # print(adjMatrix[m][n])
        if m != n and adjMatrix[m][n] == 0:
            if m < n:
                print(m,n)
                t = 0
                for team in f2:
                    if m == t:
                        print(team)
                    if n == t:
                        print(team)
                    t += 1
            # Is this elif statement necessary as we sort through the teams?
            elif m > n:
                print(n,m)

# for team in f2:
#   print(team)

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

The problem with this code so far is that the "for team in f2" loop does not loop again when that line of code is called from the 'if m < n' statement. Because of this, it only prints out one match-up that has yet to play but not the other match-up which was not played as well.

There's supposed to be 2 yet-to-be-played match-ups from this (0-3 and 2-3) so it prints the names listed for 0-3 but not for 2-3.

Would like to know how to:
1. fix the issue with the for loop over file 'f2'; and
2. improve this code that I pieced together so far.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I'm using Python 3.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate one time over file f2, you have to rewind the file to start again :

```
f2.seek(0)
```

Comment: Is this command placed before I start the loop again, say t=0; f2.seek(0); before the for loop starts again?

Comment: Yes, exactly there.